Do subscribers in ROS2 have to subscribe to the same data types as publishers?
I would like to modify the message posted by the publisher directly from the subscriber side. So I tried the following method:

pass reference to modify directly on subscriber side, but it doesn't compile;
publish the object in the publisher side, the subscriber side passes in a smart pointer, it compiles and runs successfully, but it can't be modified, the modification is invalid;
Publishers directly publish smart pointers, compilation does not pass.

Based on this, I have the following questions:

How to publish smart pointers on the publisher side;
method 2, the publisher and subscriber parameter types are not the same, why can work;
why modifying references does not pass;
Below is my code:(Other files are configured correctly)

sub:
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "vel/msg/vel.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;


class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalSubscriber()
    : Node("minimal_subscriber")
    {

      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<vel::msg::Vel>("vel", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
    }

  private:
    void topic_callback(vel::msg::Vel::SharedPtr msg)
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), " X:'%f', Y:'%f', Z:'%f'", msg->vel_x,msg->vel_y,msg->vel_z);
      msg->vel_x=7.0;
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), " X:'%f', Y:'%f', Z:'%f'", msg->vel_x,msg->vel_y,msg->vel_z);

    }
    rclcpp::Subscription<vel::msg::Vel>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

pub:
#include "my_wheeltec/my_wheeltec.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <memory> 
#include "vel/msg/vel.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;
using namespace std;
//#include "../include/my_wheeltec/my_wheeltec.hpp"


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node =std::make_shared<my_car>();
    node->run(node);
    //rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<my_car>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}


my_car::my_car():Node("YUAN_SHEN_START")
{

    int serial_baud_rate = 115200;

    this->declare_parameter("serial_baud_rate", serial_baud_rate);
    
    vel_publisher = this->create_publisher<vel::msg::Vel>("vel", 10);

}

void my_car::run(std::shared_ptr<my_car> bot )
{
    auto vel_msg=std::make_shared<vel::msg::Vel>();
    vel_msg->vel_x = 1.0;
    vel_msg->vel_y = 2.0;
    vel_msg->vel_z = 3.0;
    while (1)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(bot->get_logger(), "YUAN_SHEN_START111");
        vel_publisher->publish(vel_msg);
    }
}


I believe you should take a look at message loaning for this use case.
